# CSV file Missing Row Separator , how to read it in c #?

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers, fileparsing

My CSV File Is as below ,

```
Name,Place,                   <<--- Headers
Panindra,India,
Kumar,India,
```

As one can see the csv file contains extra "Comma"  at end of each line instead of blank . and  Row Breaker / Line Seperator is missing and hence Its showing error in parsing csv file in "FILE HELPERS" . getting error as 
"extra comma is found at the end of filed ['Place'] "

how to solve this issue ??

my Delimiter CLass goes like this

```
using FileHelpers;
namespace CsvReader.Model
{ 

        [DelimitedRecord(",")]

        public class CSVModel
        {

        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public string Name;

        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public string Place;

}}

    ...
```

and Parsing Code is like this ...

...

```
 engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<CSVModel>();
                this.engine.Options.IgnoreFirstLines = 1;

engine.BeginReadFile(fullpath);

...
```

Comment: please update question with code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you attempting to manage this currently?

Comment: @Ben I tried using FILEHELPER , but failing solve this issue , one thing I can do is read csv file escape "," at every 2 fields using REGEX ,but I want something simple ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could write something to preprocess the files like

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);

for (int i=0;i<readText.length;i++)
{
    readText[i]=readText[i].Trim([',']);
}

File.WriteAllLines(path, readText);
```

Comment: are you suggesting me to  rewrite CSV file  by removing all "," ??  I want only remove the comma at end of the line in each row ..

Comment: Trim wont look in the middle of a line, only the beginning and end, so it will work